# laravel eloquent problem with multiple when condition

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have this code

```
public function getUsers(){
        $announcement = $this;
        return User::query()
            ->when($announcement->users, function($query) use ($announcement) {
                $query->whereIn('id', $announcement->users->pluck('id')->toArray());
            })
            ->when($announcement->userTypes, function($query) use ($announcement) {
                $query->whereIn('user_type_id', $announcement->userTypes->pluck('id')->toArray());
            })
            ->when($announcement->organizations, function($query) use ($announcement) {
                $query->whereIn('organization_id', $announcement->organizations->pluck('id')->toArray());
            })
            ->when($announcement->organizations, function($query) use ($announcement) {
                $query->whereHas('organization', function($q) use ($announcement) {
                    $q->where('organization_type_id', $announcement->organizationTypes->pluck('id')->toArray());
                });
            })
            ->get();
    }
```

when I run this, what it returns is an empty array, however there is data that matches the given conditions and it is not because it does not return it to me

Comment: Can you show us a record that should match?.

Comment: What if two or more `when` conditions are true? You'll have a query with multiple `AND WHERE column IN (....)`. Maybe the generated query is not what you think it is.